# How to avoid constant rehash in zsh with local binaries?

Tags: zsh

I have a "virtual env" like setup, where a script prepends a bunch of local executables to `$PATH`. After setting everything up the script calls `hash -r`.  In bash this works perfectly:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
foo # foo is venv/bin/foo
bar # bar is venv/bin/bar
```

Once the environment is set up it stays there until you call `deactivate`.  In zsh the environment is initially set up fine, but after a while (the delay appears to be nondeterministic) it will stop working until `rehash` is called:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
foo # foo is venv/bin/foo
bar # bar is venv/bin/bar
bar # bar is /usr/bin/bar ??
rehash
bar # bar is /venv/bin/bar
```

If it's relevant, `venv/bin/foo` is a link to a script which dispatches on `$0`, calling another script and ultimately running `foo` inside a particular docker container.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: is `$PATH` changing somehow in between these invocations? Maybe you have some hooks or something which modify `PATH` briefly and call another command named `bar` causing the hash to be changed?

Comment: @muru that would make sense, but I can't find it if so.  I was able to reproduce locally just by running `venv/bin/run ls` (which doesn't touch $PATH) twice; but then I couldn't reproduce with exactly these steps again.  Something weirdly nondeterministic is going on here.  I'm happy to post the actual source for these scripts if it helps (assuming company agrees: I'm checking), but I didn't want to spam the question (I was hoping there's some known quirk of zsh I'm running into).

Comment: Ah, I have a reliable reproducing case, I'll see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: Whilst I have no idea why this is happening I've discovered a workaround by wrapping he underlying runner in a function in `activate` and calling rehash from that function (in the shell's context).